# Perl, array of matches for group of precompiled regexps

Tags: regex, perl

I have group of some regexps and want to match current line for each of them, if match succeeded call some function with matched groups as parameters.

```
my %regexps = (
    "a" => qr/^(a)\s*(b)/o,
    "b" => qr/^(c)\s*(d)/o,
    "c" => qr/^(e)\s*(f)/o,
);

sub call_on_match {
    my $actions = shift;
    # ... some setup actions for $_
    while (my ($regexp, $func) = each(%$actions) ) {
        if (my @matches = /$regexp/){
            $func->(@matches);
        }
    }
}

call_on_match({ 
    $regexps{"a"} => \&some_funca,
    $regexps{"b"} => \&some_funcb,
    $regexps{"c"} => \&some_funcc,
})
```

The problem is in `my @matches = /$regexp/` expression, it executes about 110k times and takes about 1 second total for compilation (Typical profiler output for this line: `# spent 901ms making 107954 calls to main::CORE:regcomp, avg 8µs/call`.
First guess was to remove additional regexp slashes, in case it makes perl thinks that it is new regexp and must be compiled. I used `my @matches = ($_ =~ $regexp)`, but no success.
Is there another ways to make perl not to recompile qr'ed regexps in this context?

UPD: I replaced hash with array (like `[$regexps{"a"}, \&some_funca]`):

```
foreach my $group (@$actions){
    my ($regexp, $func) = @$group;
    if (my @matches = ($_ =~ $regexp)){
           $func->(@matches);
    }
}
```

Now it compiles faster but compilation doesn't disappear: `# spent 51.7ms making 107954 calls to main::CORE:regcomp, avg 479ns/call`

Comment: By passing a Regexp object as the key of an anonymous hash, it stringifies, and is no longer a Regexp object; just a string containing a pattern.  That pattern will need to be compiled as a Regex.

Comment: ...because hash keys cannot be references (including refs to objects), they can only be immutable strings.

Comment: You probably should set up the call semantics to be something like this:  `call_on_match( [ [$re_obj1 => \&func1], [$re_obj2 => \&func2]]);`

Comment: I noticed this just after I post the question. It helps but does not resolves the problem. See UPD.

Comment: Dropping compilation time from 901ms to 51.7ms is indicative of CORE::regcomp *not* recompiling.  There is probably a call to regcomp that checks if recompilation is necessary, and that's probably inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the IDs as keys in *both* hashes, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %regexps = (
  a => qr/^(a)\s*(b)/,
  b => qr/^(c)\s*(d)/,
  c => qr/^(e)\s*(f)/,
);

sub call_on_match {

  my ($actions) = @_;

  # ... some setup actions for $_

  while (my ($regexp_id, $func) = each %$actions) {
    if (my @matches = $_ =~ $regexps{$regexp_id}) {
      $func->(@matches);
    }
  }
}

call_on_match(
  {
    a => \&some_funca,
    b => \&some_funcb,
    c => \&some_funcc,
  }
);
```

Comment: This prevents me from using of some other regexp in another script with call_on_match function loaded from module. Not quite what I want in the real program.

Comment: @SirAnthony: I am sure we could help you find a better solution if you explain the real problem. Are you saying that `call_on_match` is provided by a module, but `%regexps` is defined in the main program? I can't imagine a situation where you would know the regex but not its corresponding key in the hash. How will you call `call_on_match` if you don't what the keys are in `%regexps`?

Comment: I'll use some regexp not from `%regexps`, obviously. Actually array of regexes may be provided by some another module or such, and doesn't reside in the file where `call_on_match` do.

Comment: @SirAnthony: Well if there isn't a `%regexps` in your real problem then you have made it very difficult for us to answer you helpfully.